# Почему вид не получает данные из контроллера?

Tags: php, mvc

Я пытаюсь сделать небольшой сайт с помощью паттерна проектирования MVC. Столкнулся с проблемой: при загрузке Вида из Контроллера не приходят нужные данные.

Точка входа **index.php**:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

\core\Router::buildRoute();
```

Роутер в файле **Router.php**:

```
namespace core;
use application\controllers;
use application\models;
class Router
{
    public static function buildRoute()
    {
        //контроллер по умолчанию
        $controllerName = "IndexController";
        $modelName = "IndexModel";
        $action = "index";

        $route = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        //если URI не пустой, то определяем соотв. контроллер
        if($route[1] != '')
        {
            $controllerName = ucfirst($route[1]. "Controller");
            $modelName = ucfirst($route[1]. "Model");
        }
        include __DIR__.'/../application/controllers/'.$controllerName.'.php';
        include __DIR__.'/../application/models/'.$modelName.'.php';
        if(isset($route[2]) && $route[2] != '')
        {
            $action = $route[2];
        }

        $controllerName = '\application\controllers\IndexController';
        $controller = new $controllerName();
        $controller->$action();
    }

    public function errorPage()
    {

    }
}
```

Вот сам контроллер который отвечает за рендеринг соответствующего Вида **IndexController.php**:

```
namespace application\controllers;
use application\views\View;
use application\models\IndexModel as IndexModel;
class IndexController extends \application\controllers\Controller
{
    private $pageTemplate = '/../views/main.tpl.php';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new IndexModel();
        $this->view = new View();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->pageData['title'] = 'All tasks';
        $this->checkAdmin($_SESSION['admin']);
    }
    public function checkAdmin($sess_adm)
    {
        if($sess_adm == true)
        {
            $pageData['link'] = '/logout';
            $pageData['label'] = 'Log out';
            $pageData['mode'] = 'admin';
        }
        else
        {
            $pageData['link'] = '/auth';
            $pageData['label'] = 'Admin';
            $pageData['mode'] = 'user';
        }
        $this->view->render($this->pageTemplate, $this->pageData);

    }
}
```

Я всё перепроверил: в сессии лежат нужные данные, условия выполняются. Перед вызовом рендеринга дампал переменную `$pageData` и сессию- всё данные там лежат.

Вот родительский вида, который всё рендерит **View.php**:

```
namespace application\views;

class View
{
    public function render($tpl, $pageData)
    {
        ob_start();
        extract($pageData);
        include 'application/views/'. $tpl;
    }
}
```

Причём у меня есть другой раздел сайта, на котором виду все нужные данные передаются, но этому, почему-то, нет.

Comment: В темплейте напишите `pageData = <?php var_dump($pageData)?>` И где у вас заканчивается буферизация?

Comment: О, `$pageData['link'] = '/logout';`, `$this->`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, я просто забыл, что `$pageData` - это поле класса. Нужно было правильно обращаться так: `$this->pageData['...'] = ...`